# Creating private key & public certificate on max os x terminal - "permission denied"

Tags: macos, terminal, openssl

I'm setting up my web app to talk to Google contacts and there is a step to generate "a self-signing private key and public certificate"

I'm using the terminal app on my mac and issuing this command (which looks to be correct..replacing domain with my domain):

```
  openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -subj \
  '/C=US/ST=NY/L=New York/CN=domain.com' -keyout \
  myrsakey.pem -out myrsacert.pem
```

And this is the "permission denied" msg I'm getting as a result

```
  unable to write 'random state'
  writing new private key to 'myrsakey.pem'
  myrsakey.pem: Permission denied
```

I've checked and I have admin access on my account.  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Then please click the green check-mark next to my question, to show others, that this is the correct answer for your question (and mark the question as answered). Thanks - and welcome to stackoverflow.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, the folder you are writing to is writeable to you (it is possible to write-protect folder for admins too!).

Additionally you can try to run the command with sudo:

```
 sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -subj \
 '/C=US/ST=NY/L=New York/CN=domain.com' -keyout \
 myrsakey.pem -out myrsacert.pem
```

You then have to authorize the command with your root-password, and the openssl-command will be run with superuser-rights.